# HttpListener prevent Timeout

Tags: c#-3.0

I Implemented a `HttpListener` to process **SoapRequests**. This works fine but I can't find a soloution for the problem, that some soap-requests take too much time, resulting in timeouts on client side.

How do I let the requesting client know, that his request is not a timeout?

I thought about sending "dummy"-information while the request gets processsed, but the HttpListener only seems to send the data when you `Close` the response-object, and this can be done only once, so this is not the right thing to do I suppose.

Soloution:

```
Thread alliveWorker = new Thread(() =>
{
    try
    {
        while (context.Response.OutputStream.CanWrite)
        {
            context.Response.OutputStream.WriteByte((byte) ' ');
            context.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
    finally
    {

    }
});

alliveWorker.Start();


doWork();

alliveWorker.Interrupt();

createTheRealResponse();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending dummy information is not a bad idea.

I think you need to call the `Flush()` method on the `HttpListenerResponse`'s `OutputStream` property after writing the dummy data. You must also enable `SendChunked` property:

Try sending a dummy space at regular interval:

```
response.SendChunked = true;
response.OutputStream.WriteByte((byte)' ');
response.OutputStream.Flush();
```

Comment: Thats what I thought too, but this doesnt seem to work. It sends the whole information in one chunk, when i Close the Response.

Comment: Did you set the `SendChunked` property?

Answer (score 0):

I see two options - increase timeouts on client side or extend protocol with operation status requests from client for long running operations.

Comment: I was hoping to not do this, but I guess that will be the way then when there is no other suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .net 4.5, take a look at the [HttpListenerTimeoutManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.timeoutmanager.aspx), you can use this class as a base to implement custom timeout behaviour.